# WinAPI Click OK remote desktop works only when window is active

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

I have a timer in winforms that looks for a specific OK dialog on my server (it clicks OK on a third party application that runs out of memory, then restarts it -- there is no other work around).  So, when I remote desktop the server and the remote desktop window is active (the actual remote desktop window is active, not the actual window that has the OK that has to be clicked.  I can have a window that has nothing to do with the OK, and it works), the program works as it should.  It finds the window of the OK, then clicks the OK button fine.  When I am not in remote destop, or when the remote desktop window is not active (or selecte) it finds the window and finds the OK button, but cannot click the OK button.

So here is what I am using in my timer to click the OK:

```
Private Sub TimerCloseOK_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerCloseOK.Tick
    Dim dialogBoxText As String = "My Program - Application Error"
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("#32770", dialogBoxText)
    Dim WindowID As String = hwnd.ToString
    Dim buttonTitle As String
    buttonTitle = "OK"
    Dim dialogButtonHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK")
    If Len(WindowID) > 0 And Integer.Parse(WindowID) <> 0 Then
        'CLICK OK
        SendMessage(dialogButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 1, 0)
        mbCounter = mbCounter + 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        lCount.Text = mbCounter
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Input faking and most input mechanisms don't work when the session is locked/logged out. I don't have a source for this, but I've seen it happen with ClickYes and other utilities

Comment: Send the BN_CLICKED notification directly to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
dim control1 as Control = Control.FromHandle(hwnd)
dim button1 as Button = TryCast(control1, Button)
If button1 IsNot Nothing Then button1.PerformClick()
```

Edit: Assuming that you want to perform a ButtonClick on a Windows.Forms.Button that belongs to your project (otherwise `Control.FromHandle` will return nothing even for a valid handle).

Comment: No, this is a 3rd party application.  It does not belong to my project.  The api works when the remote desktop is active (logged in).